# '<=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray' (but LHS is pd.Timestamp)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

code:

```py
print(min_time.__class__, min_time, times.__class__)
print(max_time.__class__, max_time)
mask = (times >= min_time) * (times <= max_time)
```

yields:

> <class> 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2020-02-12
> 00:00:00+00:00 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>
> <class> 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2020-02-12 00:00:00+00:00
>
> '<=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and
> 'numpy.ndarray'

What gives? LHS is clearly `pandas.Timestamp`, and RHS clearly `numpy.ndarray`. Did something magical happen to my types?

Comment: Can you try with reversed the arguments, i.e. max_time >= times

Comment: Tried that, but same result

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: Found the issue. The `times` array was a `numpy.ndarray` of `string`s instead of `datetime.datetime`s. Still doesn't explain the misleading error message.